# Why doesn't Firefox prompt for restart to update?

Tags: firefox-automatic-updates

I'm on Ubuntu, using a copy of Firefox downloaded from Mozilla, not through a package manager.

When I restarted Firefox today I got a page informing about some new features in 69.0. It seemed to me updates downloaded some time ago but Firefox didn't prompt for restart so that they could be installed, so I tested it by downloading 68.02 (the previous version), creating a new profile, leaving it to run for some time and then looking in the About dialog and there was a button saying "Restart to update" (or something to that effect). It seems again updates downloaded but Firefox didn't prompt for restart.

I think this isn't expected behavior. Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

My Firefox installations on both Windows and OSX machines behave in the same way, so I'm assuming it actually is expected behaviour. Agree it does seem strange though, maybe somebody else can shed some more light..